# Error Building Android Kernel Module on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, makefile, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to build a hello world kernel module and load it on to my google nexus 5. I have succeeded in building the entire android kernel as a way of checking to make sure my kernel files are in order. Here is the version of the kernel that I checked out from git:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm -b android-msm-hammerhead-3.4-lollipop-release
```

Here is my module, hello-1.c:

```
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h>     /* Needed for the macros */

static int hello3_data __initdata = 3;

static int __init hello_3_init(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello, world %d\n", hello3_data);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit hello_3_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye, world 3\n");
}

module_init(hello_3_init);
module_exit(hello_3_exit);
```

I am making this module with the following Makefile:

```
obj-m := hello-1.o

KDIR = ~/kernel2/
COMPDIR = ~/linaro3/bin/arm-eabi-

all:
    $(MAKE) ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=$(COMPDIR) -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd)     modules
clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(shell pwd) clean
```

And here is the output of my Makefile:

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/linaro3/bin/arm-eabi- -C ~/kernel2/ M=/home/isaac/modules modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/isaac/kernel2'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: "__aeabi_unwind_cpp_pr1" [/home/isaac/modules/hello-1.ko] undefined!
WARNING: "printk" [/home/isaac/modules/hello-1.ko] undefined!
  CC      /home/isaac/modules/hello-1.mod.o
/home/isaac/modules/hello-1.mod.c:8:1: error: variable '__this_module' has initializer but incomplete type
/home/isaac/modules/hello-1.mod.c:9:2: error: unknown field 'name' specified in initializer
/home/isaac/modules/hello-1.mod.c:9:2: warning: excess elements in struct initializer [enabled by default]
error, forbidden warning: hello-1.mod.c:9
make[2]: *** [/home/isaac/modules/hello-1.mod.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/isaac/kernel2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

However, I have actually run make menuconfig in my kernel root folder and enabled loadable module support,forced module loading, checked module unloading, and forced module unloading. This worked for people on other stackoverflow threads but did not work for me. I can answer further questions regarding specifics if they are posted as comments. Thanks!

Comment: In the `Makefile` replace `~/` with `$HOME` for `KDIR` and `COMPDIR`

Comment: please check .config file and see whether "CONFIG_MODULES=y" option is enabled or not.